# How do I remove [] and '' when printing from a csv file python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help with this current problem with my homework. One if the requirements is to print a csv file without the `[]` and `''`.

I've tried `','.join` and that hasn't worked. not sure what else to do.

```
import csv                                            
def Main():
    myfile = open('Challenges_2.csv','r')
    with open('Challenges_2.csv', 'r') as options:
        reader = csv.reader(options)

for row in reader:
  x = 0
  for x in range (0,1):
    print(row)
```

It would print the challenges as:

```
Challenge 1 Calculator 
Challenge 2 Area
Challenge 3 Volume
```

Comment: This code does not seem to try to solve the described problem. Your problem is databound and no data is presented. How can we help with the information provided?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code that tries to accomplish your task. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: what's wrong with. `print(*row)`

Answer (score 1):

You were close with `','.join`, but since you want them separated by spaces it should be `' '.join`:

```
for row in reader:
    print(' '.join(row))
```